# Displaying view variables in template with Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django, and am working on a project where I use forms to get a user to enter a stock symbol and then using urllib I pull the data from Yahoo and return it. However, I'm not sure how to do this.

Here is my forms.py:

```
class Search(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def search(request):
context = RequestContext(request) 

if request.method == 'POST':
    search = Search(data=request.POST)

    if search.is_valid():
        success = True
        subject = search.cleaned_data['search']
        sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+subject).read()
        pbr = sourceCode.split('Price/Book (mrq):</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]


    else:
        print search.errors
else:
    search = Search()


return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"search":search},  context)
```

This is the form I use to get users input (it has some bootstrap styling):

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" action="/search/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter stock symbol" name="search">
</div>
<button type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And finally here is my search.html file where I'd like to display the data:

```
{% extends 'ui/base.html' %}

{% block title %} {{ search.search.value|upper }} {% endblock %}

{% block body_block %}

<div class="container">
<h2>{{ search.search.value|upper }}</h2>
<h2>{{ I'd like to display 'pbr' (as definied in my views.py) here }}</h2>

{% endif %}    
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What I's like to do is take the pbr from my views.py and display it in my templates. Anyone know if I can do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a `result` dictionary in your view as:

```
result = {}
if search.is_valid():
    success = True
    subject = search.cleaned_data['search']
    sourceCode = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s="+subject).read()
    pbr = sourceCode.split('Price/Book (mrq):</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">')[1].split('</td>')[0]
    result['pbr'] = pbr
    result['search'] = search
```

and return this `result` as:

```
return render_to_response('ui/search.html', {"result":result},  context)
```

In your template now you can access the `pbr` as:

```
<h2>{{ result.search.value|upper }}</h2>
<h2>{{ result.pbr }}</h2>
```

Comment: YES! This is perfect, thank you. It displays the 'pbr' but the 'result.search.value' does not display the text the user inputted.

Comment: It could probably be `result.search.search.value`

Comment: Never mind, I solved it using a .cleaned_data to display the input. And again thanks for the help (I was waiting for the time limit to accept the answer).